# How to remove the tax on goods for a particular area, or those who make delivery to this area?

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

Can this be done from the admin or will I have to write the code? If with admin, then where can I set it up?

I have a delivery in Ireland and United Kingdom how to make in Ireland there was no tax on the goods, and those who ordered delivery in Ireland also did not have tax on the goods?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it from admin. follow below steps:

- Login to admin
- Go to Stores->Tax Zones and Rates. Now you can edit tax rule which you have created.
- you can add location based on Zip/Post Code also.

Comment: And how to add postcode, now I enter in the form of postcode je1 writes that wrong zip code ?